# How to use nonce in a login system using php to avoid replay attack?

Tags: php, security, authentication, nonce

I have created a login and registration system using php. I intend to use nonces to prevent the replay attack. So far what I have is, generating a random number using  `(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));` and then store this on the database, and pass the same data in a hidden field to the client end, and then send it back to the server side, when the login button is clicked. if it matches the on in the database, the user is redirected to the private page, and then a new nonce is generated and updated in the database.

This is how i intend to implement it. But I'm some how not totally sure of the implementation.

Comment: Don't use `mt_rand()` as the "random" number could be predictable - use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead to stop any attacker successfully predicting your value for use in their replay attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
//Check nonce against session
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST["nonce"] === $_SESSION["csrf"]){
    //save data
    //redirect
}
//generate new nonce for form
$_SESSION["csrf"] = uniqid(mt_rand(),true);
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf']; ?>"/>
    <!-- other form fields -->
    <!-- submit button -->
</form>
```

Comment: However there still exists a problem with this. As long as the session is up and running, it is vulnerable to the attack. But if the session ends, then it works fine. Isn't that right?

Comment: You are right to some extent, but even if session is up and running, they need to have a new nonce for each submit request. So if they want to replay, they will need new nonce. This is called CSRF protection.

Comment: However, if you want to prevent user from brute forcing passwords on login, keep a track of wrong password attempts and show captcha if number of wrong passwords are more than three. On successful login from same ip, reset wrong passwords counter to zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php sessions for this purpose.
Session is a more conventional and useful approach for login purposes.
After recieving form data validate that data and then storing that data in session will work.

Answer (score 0):

`uniqid(mt_rand(),true)` is not appropriate for a nonce value:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

> It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the
>   » Mersenne Twister, which will produce random numbers four times
>   faster than what the average libc rand() provides.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

> his function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and
>   should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a
>   cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(),
>   random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

`random_bytes` and `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` return characters that are not printable, but you can convert them to hexadecimal representations:

```
bin2hex(random_bytes($length))
```

Make sure the nonces cache storage is not available to other users. For instance, PHP sessions are usually saved as files inside the /tmp folder. If you're using SESSIONS, override their default behaviour:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

Anyway, I developed and released a nonces library:

- https://github.com/pedroac/nonce4php
- https://packagist.org/packages/pedroac/nonce

This is how you could create a form with a nonce using the library:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$form = new \pedroac\nonce\Form\NonceForm(
    'token',
    new \pedroac\nonce\NoncesManager(
      new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\PdoAdapter($pdo)
    )
);
if ($form->isSubmittedInvalid()) {
  /**
   * handle failure
   */
}
if ($form->isSubmittedValid()) {
  /**
   * handle the success
   */
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <?= new HtmlNonceField($form) ?>
    <input type="submit" name="myform" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You could also do it like this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$manager = new \pedroac\nonce\NoncesManager(
    new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\PdoAdapter($pdo)
);
$lastNonceName = $_SESSION['nonce_name'];
if(isset($_POST[$lastNonceName]) && $manager->verifyAndExpire($lastNonceName, $_POST[$lastNonceName])) {
    // handle success
}

$nonce = $manager->create();
session_start();
$_SESSION['nonce_name'] = $nonce->getName();
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden"
           name="<?= htmlspecialchars($nonce->getName()) ?>"
           value="<?= htmlspecialchars($nonce->getValue()) ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="myform" value="Submit" />
</form>
```